# My "return" statement isn't working even when there are no other code branches

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

I have a method that attempts to create an `AudioRecord`. Different phones support different  sample rates, channel configs and audio formats. So the method tries to create an `AudioRecord` for each of them and return the first that works.

```
private AudioRecord getAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate: sampleRates) {
        for (int audioFormat: audioFormats) {
            for (int channelConfig: channelConfigs) {
                String description = rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat
                        + ", channel: " + channelConfig;

                Log.d(TAG, "Trying: " + description);

                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                if (bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR
                        || bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed: This rate/channel config/format is not supported");
                    continue;
                }

                AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
                if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed: Recorder is uninitialized");
                    continue;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Success: " + description);
                return recorder;
            }
        }
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Failed all rates. Does the device have a microphone?");
    return null;
}
```

The problem is `return recorder` never happens!

Here is my logcat output:

[image: Logcat output]

On the highlighted line (8000 / 3 / 12) there is no error, but also no success.

If I use no `continue` as said in the comments below, it still doesn't return!

```
private AudioRecord getAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate: sampleRates) {
        for (int audioFormat: audioFormats) {
            for (int channelConfig: channelConfigs) {
                String description = rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat
                        + ", channel: " + channelConfig;

                Log.d(TAG, "Trying (2): " + description);

                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR && bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
                    if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Success: " + description);
                        return recorder;
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed: Recorder is uninitialized");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed: This rate/channel config/format is not supported");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Failed all rates. Does the device have a microphone?");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The same pattern (a logged attempt without a following success or failure) happens 3 other times in the log as well. It almost feels like a try/catch block is eating an exception (or issuing a silent continue statement). Is the code sample you've provided *exactly* what generated the log?

Comment: This is indeed strange. Have you tried testing for the inverse conditions and nesting your if blocks, and thus not using `continue`?

Comment: Like @SeanReilly mentions, it really seems like this is not the code that is generating the log output.  Two `Trying` messages in a row do now seem possible unless there is a `break;` or `continue;` that is missing from your code listing.  Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your application to make sure the classes are up to date? Habe you tried using the debugger and stepping through the code?

Comment: The only other code run before this is: `new RealTimeAudioRecorder().start();` and `final AudioRecord audioRecord = getAudioRecord();`. There is no try-catch. @Sean Reilly Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I just did that (code in the question) and it still doesn't work!

Comment: And there's no AOP, or any other AST/bytecode manipulation that could be adding try/catch blocks between compilation and execution?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the return statement, you simply never reach it because your AudioRecord never initializes (Most examples out there don't check it, even though they probably should)

As a brief sanity check you may want to check your Manifest file to [verify you have the proper permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161666/android-audiorecord-fails-to-initialize) to record audio in the first place, given that access to the microphone is a hardware feature that may/may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function in a `try`/`catch` block and you will probably find that something is causing an exception to be thrown.

Comment: If an exception was thrown, it would go up to the call stack until its caught. The iteration would stop immediately.